# HTML5 Form validation - error message customization

Tags: javascript, html, input, error-handling

I have a form with an input like this.

```html
<input type="text" name="question" class="form-control" required="" minlength="4" maxlength="2" size="20" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('please enter something')">
```

Now the default validation messages work great. But I want to set custom messages for specific rules.

i.e. for rules like `required` `minlength` `maxlength` when each fails I want to provide a custom error message specific to the rule that failed.

I have tried `oninvalid="setCustomValidity('please enter something')"` but that sets that message for every rule.

How can I specify custom error messages for specific rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setCustomValidity` property to change validation messages and  `validity` property to find type of validation error

> validity   : A ValidityState object describing the validity state of the element.

Upon form load `validate` property is initialized for each form element and updated on every validation due to user events like keypress,change etc. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) you can find the possible values

```
var email = document.getElementById("mail");

if (email.validity.valueMissing) {
  email.setCustomValidity("Don't be shy !");
}
else{
  event.target.setCustomValidity("");
}

email.addEventListener("input", function (event) {

  if (email.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Don't be shy !");
  }
  else{
    event.target.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/91kc2c9a/2/

Note: For some unknown reason email validation is not working in the above fiddle but should work fine locally

More on ValidityState [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

Comment: yes that is what i was looking for. your references help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `oninvalid` event occurs when the input is invalid, in your case, the input is required and if it is empty, `oninvalid` will occur. (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_oninvalid.asp))

And yes, `maxlength` should be bigger than `minlength` and instead of `required=""` you can simply write `required` 
if your code is like this (with an ID 'input-field'):

`<input type="text" name="question" id="input-field" class="form-control" required="" minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="20" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('please enter something')">`

You will need to add custom functions to check different validation and display different errors based on them.

The `validator()` function bellow triggers when the input box loses focus and checks for its requirements, and the `valdiator_two()` is triggered on every keypress in the input field:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("input-field");
function validator(){
    if (field.value === "") {
      alert("You can't leave this empty");
    }
    if (field.value !== "" && field.value.length < 4){
      alert("You have to enter at least 4 character");
    } 
}

function validator_two(){
    if (field.value.length >= 8){
      alert("You can't enter more than 8 character");
    }
}

field.addEventListener("blur", validator);
field.addEventListener("input", validator_two);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="question" id="input-field" class="form-control" required="" minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="20" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('please enter something')">
```

Comment: thanks but my question was about how can i customize the default error messages.. I am now using  custom validation using jquery for now, because using custom error messages was a requirement for my project.

Comment: In that case, does the first answer from Novice help ?