# Multiple custom validility messages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sign up form and I want to display a different CustomValidity message for if it's not been entered or if it's not between 6 and 14. This is the Input:

```html
<input 
    type="password" 
    pattern=".{6,14}"
    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')" 
    placeholder="Enter Password" 
    name="psw" 
    id="psw" 
    required>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should probably select the element with document.querySelector() and then write some logic.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? We are happy to help but you should show what you've tried and we can help if you have issues. This is not a site to ask someone to write the code for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Form validation - error message customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40037873/html5-form-validation-error-message-customization)